# Can I do a WP Query within X days of today's date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've got a little bit of code that returns some info from a CPT (pre_jobs) when a certain taxonomy is selected (repeat) and sorts it by an ACF date field (pre_job_due_date)

What I'd like to do is filter these results so that only the ones show that are in the near future - the idea is that we can contact the client to book the work in, say within 6 weeks of today's date, then change to a different taxonomy when we're awaiting a reply or the job gets booked. Basically a custom to-do list. How would I add a filter that shows these? Some jobs will repeat in 5 years time so I don't want a massive list. So far I've got:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'pre_jobs',
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'pre_job_due_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pre_job_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'repeat' )
        ),
    ),
));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? The given code does not contain anything for that requirement about six weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calculating the date in 6 weeks with Php, you can use the wp `meta_query` argument in your query

```
$before_date = date("Ymd", strtotime("+6 weeks"));

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'pre_jobs',
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'pre_job_due_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
     'key' => 'pre_job_due_date',
     'value' => $before_date, 
     'compare' => '<', 
     ),
   ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pre_job_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'repeat' )
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Still returns all the options with this no matter what the date is - does the ACF date have to be in a Y-m-d format?

Comment: I updated my answer `$before_date = date("Ymd"...` which is the default ACF pro date format. Plz let me know if its working for you.

Comment: Hi gael - yes that's what I've used - I've been into the acf settings and changed the return format to this also - it still displays all the CPTs no matter what the due date is

Comment: I updated my answer with `meta_query` instead of `date_query` which isn't much documented